# How does the function $f(q)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} q^p$ behave near $q=1$?

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I wonder, is there an elementary or other closed-form function $g(q)$ which behaves like $$f(q)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} q^p$$ near $q=1$?

The plot of $f(q)$ looks like the following, but I failed to find an elementary function with a similar behavior near $q=1$:

[image]

Comment: What type of "similar" are you looking for? $q+q^2+q^3+...=\frac{1}{1-q}-1$ is similar in some sense.

Comment: @Quarantino by similar I mean approaching each other.

Comment: I wonder if the behaviour of $f$ near $1$ depends on more than the fact that the $n$th prime is roughly $n\ln(n)$. In other words, if $Q$ is another set of integers whose $n$-th member in ascending order is $\sim n\ln(n)$, do you get the same behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a perhaps slightly more pedestrian solution that leads to the concrete asymptotic behaviour of your function.

As $q\to1$, your sum averages over more and more primes, so asymptotically it doesn’t depend on the details of the distribution of the primes. Thus, we can replace the sum over the primes by an integral over their density $\frac1{\log p}$:

$$
\sum_pq^p\sim\int_a^\infty q^p\frac{\mathrm dp}{\log p}\;,
$$

where I left the lower limit $a$ unspecified; it doesn’t matter asymptotically and will drop out in due course. Now set $q=1-\epsilon$ to find

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_a^\infty q^p\frac{\mathrm dp}{\log p}
&=&
\int_a^\infty(1-\epsilon)^p\frac{\mathrm dp}{\log p}
\\
&=&
\int_a^\infty\mathrm e^{p\log(1-\epsilon)}\frac{\mathrm dp}{\log p}
\\
&\sim&
\int_a^\infty\mathrm e^{-\epsilon p}\frac{\mathrm dp}{\log p}
\\
&=&
\int_{\epsilon a}^\infty\mathrm e^{-x}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\epsilon\log\frac x\epsilon}
\\
&=&
\frac1\epsilon\int_{\epsilon a}^\infty\mathrm e^{-x}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\log x-\log\epsilon}
\\
&=&
-\frac1{\epsilon\log\epsilon}\left(\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx+\frac1{\log\epsilon}\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-x}\log x\mathrm dx+O\left(\frac1{\log^2\epsilon}\right)\right)
\\
&=&
-\frac1{\epsilon\log\epsilon}\left(1-\frac{\gamma}{\log\epsilon}+O\left(\frac1{\log^2\epsilon}\right)\right)\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). Thus

$$
\sum_pq^p\sim-\frac1{(1-q)\log(1-q)}\;.
$$

To visualize the asymptotic behaviour, we can look at the reciprocal of your function:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\sum_pq^p\right)^{-1}
&=&
-\epsilon\log\epsilon\left(1-\frac{\gamma}{\log\epsilon}+O\left(\frac1{\log^2\epsilon}\right)\right)^{-1}\;,
\\
&=&
-\epsilon\left(\log\epsilon+\gamma+O\left(\frac1{\log\epsilon}\right)\right)^{-1}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

This shows why I carried along the term in $\epsilon\log^{-2}\epsilon$, even though it’s not part of the leading asymptotic behaviour, as it leads to a term linear in $\epsilon$ in the reciprocal that we need for a good comparison.

Here’s a graph of the reciprocal of your function (in purple) compared to $-(1-q)(\log(1-q)+\gamma)$ (in green):

[image: graph of reciprocal of function compared to asymptote]

Comment: I wonder why in the answer do you omit the Euler's constant while in the comparison you do use it.

Comment: @Anixx: You hadn't specified precisely what you meant by "similar behaviour". You answered a question about this with "by similar I mean approaching each other". I took that to mean that you wanted an elementary function that your function is [asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) to. For that purpose, the second term isn't required, since $1-\frac\gamma{\log\epsilon}\to1$ as $\epsilon\to0$. But for the graphical comparison of the reciprocals the linear term is important, as the logarithmic singularity is so weak that a difference by a linear term is prominent.

Comment: I built a plot for $f(q)+\frac1{(1-q)(\ln(1-q)+\gamma)}$ and it does not seem to approach zero...

Comment: @Anixx: No, it doesn't. That's not what asymptotic means; see the link above. If that's what you wanted, you should have specified it in the question.

Comment: @Anixx: It will typically be very hard to find a function whose difference to a divergent function approaches zero. That's why one performs asymptotic analysis and finds functions whose ratio to the function approaches $1$.

Comment: @Anixx: To understand how difficult it would be to find a function whose difference to your function approaches zero, note that for $q\to1$ your function effectively counts the primes until $p\epsilon$ becomes appreciable. So a function whose difference to this function approaches zero would also have to count these primes. That would certainly not be an elementary function.

Comment: this is pity. Indeed this is what I wanted.

Comment: @Anixx: What you can do, though, if that's of any use to you, is to continue the series expansion. E.g. the next term after $1-\frac\gamma{\log\epsilon}$ would be

$$
\frac1{\log^2\epsilon}\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-x}\log^2x\mathrm dx=\frac{\gamma^2+\frac{\pi^2}6}{\log^2\epsilon}\;.
$$

But no matter how many factors of $\log\epsilon$ you have in the denominator, they won't make up for the factor $\epsilon$ in the denominator in front of the parenthesis, so these corrections all diverge (which means that any finite sum of them will also diverge).

Comment: @Anixx: And even if you could somehow sum this entire series (which I'm pretty sure you can't), you'd still be left with the $O(1)$ errors e.g. from dropping the integral from $0$ to $\epsilon a$, from approximating the sum by an integral, etc. Getting this function right to order $O(1)$ would essentially mean solving all prime counting problems.

Comment: If you are interested where this came from, I was trying to evaluate the numerocity of primes following the method described here: https://mathenchant.wordpress.com/2018/09/16/a-new-game-with-infinity/

Comment: @Anixx: Thanks, that's interesting. But note that that post forms not only differences of these functions of $q$ but also ratios, e.g. it finds that there are $\sqrt2$ times as many triangular numbers as square numbers. So you can't use this result to say "there are $5$ more primes than numbers in set $S$", but you *can* say "there are twice as many primes as numbers in set $S$ – e.g. there are twice as many primes as there are primes with residue $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: Well, it would be less precise measure if we omit the finite terms. I think the finite terms are important when comparing infinite sets.

Comment: @Anixx: Well, yes, at the level of precision that you're aiming for, everything is important. I'm just saying that that's not possible :-) (with current methods). But note that the finite terms are only important if you want to know the difference. If you want the ratio, as in the case of the triangular and square numbers in the blog post, then you can omit any finite terms and still get the same ratio.

Comment: I am not sure the ratio would be the same if we omit the finite terms. If we interpret those numerocities as some kind of numbers then $P/Q\ne P/(Q+a)$. Moreover, the difference between them would not be some kind of an infinitesimal. For instance, if we take the numerocity of non-negative integers $\omega_+= num(0,1,2...)$ and the numerocity of the set $\tau=num (1/2,3/2,5/2...)$, which is equal to the numerocities of even or odd numbers, the difference is $\omega_+-\tau=1/2$, yet $\operatorname{reg}(\frac1{\omega_+}-\frac1{\tau})=-\frac{\pi^2}3$

Comment: @Anixx: I'm not very familiar with the whole infinitesimal / non-classical analysis aspect of this. I'm only speaking in the terms that you used in the question. If you consider two series that diverge for $q\to\infty$, then the limit of their ratio for $q\to\infty$ doesn't depend (in a classical setting) on any finite number of their terms (since those are eventually drowned out by the divergent sum that comes after them).

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the prime number theorem and partial summation that as $x\to 0,x >0$ $$\sum_p e^{-px} \sim \sum_{n\ge 2} \frac{e^{-nx}}{\log n}$$
The RH gives an error term $O(\sum_n n^{-1/2+\epsilon}e^{-nx})$.

> The residue theorem explicit formula gives more information.

As usual we look at the simpler series
$$\sum_n \Lambda(n)e^{-nx}=\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} \frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\Gamma(s)x^{-s}ds$$ $$=\sum Res(\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\Gamma(s)x^{-s})=x^{-1}-\sum_\rho \Gamma(\rho) x^{-\rho}+f(x)+g(x)\log x$$ where $f,g$ are entire.

The latter series stays true by analytic continuation for $\Re(x) > 0$ using the density of zeros and the $\sqrt{\pi} e^{-\pi t/2}$ decay of $\Gamma(1/2+it)$ obtained from $\pi/\sin(\pi s)=\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)$. When separating the $\Im(\rho)>0$ and $\Im(\rho)<0$ parts we get two functions that can be analytically continued along either clockwise or counterclockwise rotation around $0$. The same analysis works for $\sum_{p^k}\frac1k e^{-p^k x}$ and $\sum_p e^{-px}$ except that we'll get ugly $li(x^{-\rho})$ terms.

> $f(x)+g(x)\log x$ corresponds more or less to $\sum_n n^{-1}\Lambda(n)e^{-x/n}$, this is the functional equation.